# How to access subdir within images folder (getting 404)?

Tags: spring-mvc

I've added a new subdir within my images folder and cannot get the new images to resolve.

> Failed to load resource: ... 404 (Not Found)
>   `http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/content/images/subdir/mysubdirimage.png`

My directory structure:

```
src
-- main
   --java
   --webapp
     --content
        --images    // <- these resolve
          --subdir  // <- new subdir...resolve fail for images
```

I have tried adding the following but does't work:

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/content/**" location="/content/" />
```

mvc-dispatcher-servelet.xml:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
 <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/content/**" location="/content/" />  //<-- Added this..no go!

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/views/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the folders and images?

Comment: @CurtisMattoon: 'subdir' is readonly, 'images' dir is readonly. If I put the images in 'images' dir they resolve correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are halfway there with the mvc-dispatcher-servlet line you added, but you need to change it to:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/content/images/" />
```

Also try changing the method in your controller where you are attempting to access the images to something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/staticImages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showImage() {           
  return "/images/subdir/mysubdirimage.png";
```

}

And finally, with the example above try the URL (as you were doing above):

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/images/subdir/mysubdirimage.jpg
```

You should also be able to access the images through the @RequestMapping pattern defined in your controller. For example, using the example I gave you above, you would enter the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/staticImages
```